# Where are all the enemy labs located?

Tags: advance-wars-2

So recently I found that in *Advance Wars 2*, there are secret missions you can go to by capturing some specific [cities](https://advancewars.fandom.com/wiki/City).

Which cities I should capture in order to unlock the secret missions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four city need to be capture in order to play those mission. Below I will list down the city at need to be capture and also show you which mission the city located at.

---

---

**Orange Star**

On the ***Mission 4: Flak Attack***, you need to capture the city (Red circle marked) in order to get the enemy lab map.

[image]

---

**Blue Moon**

On the ***Mission 10: Toy Box***.

[image]

---

**Yellow Comet**

On the ***Mission 19: Show Stopper***. Capture the this city will unlock the secret mission.

[image]

---

**Green Earth**

On the ***Mission 26: Sinking Feeling***. Go to the island and capture the bottom city will unlock the secret mission.

[image]